# Use nullary constructor with algebraic data type instead of wrapping with Maybe?

Tags: haskell

I was doing this type of thing in my code:

```
data MyType = Cons1 a b
data OtherType = OtherType
             { val1 :: Int
             , val2 :: String
             , val3 :: Maybe MyType
             }
```

and I was wondering if changing the code to this would be neater/simpler and what the pros/cons are:

```
data MyType = Cons1 a b | Missing
data OtherType = OtherType
             { val1 :: Int
             , val2 :: String
             , val3 :: MyType
             }
```

What I am doing is reading lines from a file into [OtherType], each line has 4 columns say with columns 3 and 4 being used to create val3 :: MyType. Currently I am using readMaybe to read a and b and then passing them to a function that returns Nothing if either of them are Nothing or Just MyType if they are Just a and Just b. I was thinking I could change this to return Missing instead thereby removing one layer of wrapping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two minor advantages of your second approach:

1. By cutting out a level of indirection, functions that you write and that traverse values of `OtherType` generally become a bit simpler (but not spectacularly).
2. By choosing a good name for the nullary constructor that you add your code may become more  self-explanatory (compared to uses of the rather generic name `Nothing` in various places).

A big disadvantage is that you lose the ability to use all the predefined functions that the standard libraries give you to work with `Maybe`-values and that you have to code the corresponding functionality yourself.

Answer (score 22):

You should only add the `Missing` constructor to `MyType` if it makes sense for all `MyType` values to have the possibility of `Missing`. You will have to handle `Missing` in all functions dealing with `MyType` values. If the majority of these would be non-total—throw an error or otherwise fail—then clearly `Missing` does not belong in `MyType` and you should just use `Maybe MyType` instead.

Simply put: if optionality is inherent in the type, encode it in the type. Otherwise, keep it separate.

Comment: N.B. This is a specific case of the principle of "no junk": when designing a data type, make anything that does not make sense completely non-representable -- make the possible values according to Haskell the exact same as the possible values in your model.